# How to convert this arrow function to a normal function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, arrow-functions, echarts

This is from a child component in Vue.js. I'm trying to pass some data from the parent in `sensorData`, but the binding isn't happening because the code below uses an arrow function for `data`. How can I convert this function to a normal function so that the `this` binding is available.

```js
export default {
  name: "SensorChart",
  props: ["sensorData"],

  data: () => ({
    chartOptionsLine: {
      xAxis: {
        data: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: "value"
      },

      series: [
        {
          type: "line",
          // data: this.sensorData
          data: [910, 423, 61, 752, 262, 3625, 119]
        }
      ],
      title: {
        text: "Sample Data",
        x: "center",
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 20
        }
      },
      color: ["#1271c2"]
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: It's `data() {` in official docs, this is the first place to check.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine.

```js
export default {
  name: "SensorChart",
  props: ["sampleData","sampleLabels"],

  data: function() { 
    return {
      chartOptionsLine: { 
        xAxis: {
          data: this.sampleLabels
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: "value"
        },

        series: [
          {
            type: "line",
            data: this.sampleData
          }
        ],
        title: {
          text: "Sensor Data",
          x: "center",
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 24
          }
        },
        color: ["#127ac2"]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: arrow should work fine too - it **always** has for me - note, `data: function() {` can be simplified to `data() {`

Comment: still can't undertand why your arrow function fails - both methods return an Object ... `this` is irrelevant

Comment: @Bravo An arrow function would *not* work in the case, where the OP is using `this` (which *is* relevant here) to get access to the `props`. The arrow function captures the outer context, which is not the component instance.

Comment: @Bravo yep, this is exactly why I always write it with a regular function: you can keep using `this` without any bad surprise. Also, the Vue snippets in VScode are doing that super quick for me too, so no real time wasted.

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function expression is a compact alternative to a traditional function expression, but is limited and can't be used in all situations.

There are differences between arrow functions and traditional functions, as well as some limitations:

- Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments or
  super, and should not be used as methods.
- Arrow functions don't have access to the new.target keyword.
- Arrow functions aren't suitable for call, apply and bind methods,
  which generally rely on establishing a scope.
- Arrow functions cannot be used as constructors.
- Arrow functions cannot use yield, within its body.

for more Details in there:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

So,if you want to use traditional way, you can use this.

```
export default {
  ...
  data: function() { return {...} }
}
```

if you want to use arrow function, While arrow functions do not have their own this pointer, only arguments can be passed when a function is called through **call()** or **apply()** (this way can't bind this).